# Use BETWEEN in Switch Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to do a custom `GROUP BY Range`.

I built the following SQL Query :

```
SELECT TheTmp, SUM(TheTmp*0.33)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Name = 'TestName1'
GROUP BY SWITCH(TheTmp BETWEEN 0 AND 5,0,50,true)
```

But it throw an error :

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'TheTmp' as part of an aggregate function.

'TheTmp' Is the right field since the below query works :

```
Select TheTmp, SUM(TheTmp*0.33)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Name = 'TestName1'
GROUP BY TheTmp
```

So I think that I use badely `BETWEEN` in my `SWITCH()`

For the following table :

```
Name        TheTmp
TestName1   8.76669265399322
TestName2   0.273812785388691
TestName1   1
TestName1   1.58938597048424
```

My goal is to get the output below (add value between 0 and 5 together)

```
TestName1   8.766*0.33
TestName1   (1.58938597048424*0.33)+(1*0.33)
```

How do I use `BETWEEN` into `SWITCH`

```
SWITCH(TheTmp BETWEEN 0 AND 5,0,50,true)
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL related questions.

Comment: How do I do a sql reproducible example ? Its not HTML/JS ?

Comment: When editing, type the data in proper columns, highlight and click `{}`.

Comment: @jarlh I Edited, Hope its more clear !

Comment: A GROUP BY requires an aggregate function (SUM(), COUNT(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX()). SWITCH() is not an aggregate function, and therefore can't be used in a GROUP BY, and you have no other aggregate functions in the GROUP BY expression. SWITCH doesn't make any sense in a GROUP BY, anyway - are you sure you understand what a GROUP BY does?

Comment: @KenWhite I think I understand what `Group By` does. Does a way exist to GROUP value by range ? 

So I've : 

0-5          VAL
5-1000    VAL
...

Comment: No, that's not what a GROUP BY does. You can do that with a CASE statement in your SELECT clause.

Comment: @KenWhite still same issue with `SELECT SWITCH()`

Comment: Nobody said anything about `SELECT SWITCH`. You don't need SWITCH at all. Use a CASE statement instead, as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @KenWhite: `CASE` is T-SQL; not valid in Access SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, Sum(0.33*[TheTmp]) AS Amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name, IIf([TheTmp]>=0 And [TheTmp]<=5,"Group1","Group2")
HAVING (((Name)="TestName1"));
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Here it is for your second request:

```
SELECT IIf([TheTmp]>=0 And [TheTmp]<=5,"Group1","Group2") AS Grouping, Sum(0.33*[TheTmp]) AS Amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY IIf([TheTmp]>=0 And [TheTmp]<=5,"Group1","Group2"), Name
HAVING ((([Name])="TestName1"));
```

[image]

And here is request number 3:

```
SELECT IIf([TheTmp]>=0 And [TheTmp]<=5,"Group1","Group2") AS Grouping, Sum(0.33*[TheTmp]) AS Amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY IIf([TheTmp]>=0 And [TheTmp]<=5,"Group1","Group2"), Name
HAVING ((([Name])="TestName1"))
ORDER BY IIf([TheTmp]>=0 And [TheTmp]<=5,"Group1","Group2") DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: @KenWhite I did try and this does work.

Comment: I didn't use `SWITCH` and it does work. Here, I'll post a pic of the result.

Comment: Is it possible to display "GROUP1","Group2" and not `Name` ?

Comment: Yes it is. Let me revise my answer.

Comment: Last Question, How would you order this if you want for example "Group2" Displayed First. Does ORDER BY work ?

Comment: Yes. You could use `ORDER BY IIf([TheTmp]>=0 And [TheTmp]<=5,"Group1","Group2") DESC` or since there are only 2 groups, you could just change the order in the `iif` statement.

Comment: I tried DESC but it seems not working `Syntax error in GROUP BY clause`

Comment: Hmm. It works for me. I'll add it the revision to my answer.

Comment: Remove `Name` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238410/discussion-between-bryan-rock-and-dorian).

Comment: I have a new issue related to your answer if you want check please [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69674016/11167163) is the link. Kindly

Answer (score 0):

`Between .. And` is *SQL* syntax. In `Switch` use *VBA* syntax:

```
TheTmp >= 0 And TheTmp <= 5
```

Comment: Switch still isn't an aggregate function, and can't be used in a GROUP BY.